# Why pygame.event.wait stops music play after 20 seconds or so

Tags: python, pygame, mp3

So... im using this code:

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('computersong.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

but the music play for like twenty seconds then stops, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[`pygame.event.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait) returns a single event from the event queue, but it does not wait until the music has finished playing.
You have to use [`pygame.time.wait`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) and to wait for specific amount of time:

```py
pygame.time.wait(5000) # wait 5 seconds
```

---

Another option is to use [`pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_busy) and to wait in a loop until the music has finished:

```py
pygame.mixer.music.play()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.poll()
    clock.tick(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from what you have written but I am guessing that your computersong.mp3 is 20 seconds and it is playing to completion and stopping. Assuming that is the case and you want it to repeat, you can try this:

From the pygame docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play), you can see that if you want the song to be repeated you can give it a value for the loop argument. If you want it to continue on looping until you stop it then you pass play **loop=-1**

> pygame.mixer.music.play()
>
> Start the playback of the music stream play(loops=0, start=0.0) ->
>   None This will play the loaded music stream. If the music is already
>   playing it will be restarted.
>
> The loops argument controls the number of repeats a music will play.
>   play(5) will cause the music to played once, then repeated five times,
>   for a total of six. If the loops is -1 then the music will repeat
>   indefinitely.

Your code then needs to go on to do something else. If the program just does that and then exits, it will of course stop.